# How to "center" the FirstPersonControls?

Tags: typescript, three.js, electron, controls

I am very beginner at 3D.. I would like to use the FirstPersonControls, but it seems like the "center" based on, is situated at top left of my browser.

It is very difficult to explain, so here is a GIF: https://gifyu.com/image/hu8x

As you can see, it can rotates while putting mouse right and down, but I cannot rotate top and left.

Here is the actual code corresponding to it (I'm using TypeScript):

**Camera.ts**

```js
import { FirstPersonControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/FirstPersonControls'

var camera: new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 )

/* Positions are for testing */
camera.position.z = 400
camera.position.y = -900
camera.rotation.x = -200

var controls = new FirstPersonControls(camera, Renderer.domElement)

export { camera as Camera, controls as Controls }
```

**main.ts**

```js
import { Camera, Controls } from './Camera'
...

let clock = new THREE.Clock()
clock.start()

...

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
  Controls.update(clock.getDelta())
  render()
}

// Sets up resize, append to container..
setup()
// Generates the cubes..
App.run()
// Animate function
animate()
```

I tried to mix a lot of old and new examples I found, but I still cannot get it to work..

Is there something I didn't understood here ?

Explanations are appreciated!

**EDIT:** I have tried some things, and it looks like i'm not using a PointerLock with it. Have tried some things, but got nothing to work properly ! Have someone an example I can try out on Electron?

Comment: I don't see the first call to `animate()`, bit maybe that inside the dots?

Comment: Yeah, editing in one seconde, sorry !